# Entity framework - Order by descending and then perform Distinct on that result returns the wrong results

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I currently have a class that looks like this

```
class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentLogId { get; set; }
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public string info { get; set; }
}
```

Now what I would like to do is to sort the result by descending based on the Id (last ones on the top) and then from those results get the distinct values (in short the sort order is important). I noticed that if I do this

//Order the students in descending order based on their id

```
List<string> lst = StudentLogHistoryModel.OrderByDescending(s => s.StudentLogId).Select(u => u.Guid).ToList<string>();
```

The above returns the correct result in the right order now I would like to only get the unique values so I tried adding to the above query and came up with this

```
List<string> lst = StudentLogHistoryModel.OrderByDescending(s => s.StudentLogId).Select(s => s.Guid).Distinct().ToList<string>();
```

However I noticed that in the second one the order got messed up. Any suggestions on why the order does not get preserved ? How can I fix this ?

What I mean by order getting messed up was suppose the first result i got this
`[A,A,B,B,D]` I was expecting to get `[A,B,D]` after the second query. However I get something like [D,A,B]

Comment: It makes more sense to me to do `Distinct()` before `OrderByDescending()` anyway. No sense in ordering values you're just going to throw away.

Comment: @itsme86 Can you show me how to do that ? If I do `.Select(s => s.Guid).Distinct()` then I cant add `OrderByDescending(s => s.StudentLogId)` after it

Comment: StudentLogHistoryModel.Distinct().OrderByDescending(s => s.StudentLogId).Select(s => s.Guid).ToList<string>()

Comment: @OctoCode how does entity know that I would like to do a distinct on the GUID column ?

Comment: The best way is to Order, group, and select First of each group.

Comment: @jdweng can you show me how to do that ?

Comment: How are you getting duplicate GUIDs in the first place? A join earlier for the data?

Comment: @AustinTFrench in the table GUID could be the same since its pointing to some other resource

Comment: List<string> lst = StudentLogHistoryModel.OrderByDescending(s => s.StudentLogId).GroupBy(s => s.StudentLogId).Select(s => s.First().Guid).ToList<string>()  I'm assuming each StudentId has the sameGUID. Otherwise, List<string> lst = StudentLogHistoryModel.OrderByDescending(s => s.StudentLogId).GroupBy(s => s.StudentLogId).SelectMany(s => s.Select(y => y.Guid).Distinct()).ToList<string>()

Comment: @jdweng let me try that

Comment: @jdweng each student necessarily doesnt need to have the same GUID. it can be different

Comment: @jdweng it does not work the sorting never gets applied

Comment: I didn't say that.  I meant "does each student have one GUID or more than one GUID".

Comment: You are only sorting by student id, not GUID.  So don't you want to output both the student id and the GUID so you know both student id and GUID?

Comment: I would only like to sort by ID.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Queryable_Distinct__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__):

> The query behavior that occurs as a result of executing an expression
>   tree that represents calling Distinct(IQueryable)
>   depends on the implementation of the type of the source parameter. The
>   expected behavior is that it returns an unordered sequence of the
>   unique items in source.

The key bit there is 'unordered'. IQueryable's `Distinct` does not guarantee that order is maintained. As such, you need to `OrderBy` **after** the `Distinct`.